# Can the Cassini maps of France be found online?

Tags: france, 18th-century, maps

I am looking for online versions of the Cassini maps (i.e. *"the first general maps of the territory using a measuring apparatus were made by the Cassini family during the 18th century"* from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_cartography) - preferably all maps combined in one map if such a thing exists. I

I tried the national library of France site (http://www.bnf.fr/fr/acc/x.accueil.html), but when I click on a Cassini map, it always gives me the message *"La page recherchée n'existe pas !"* (the page you were looking for does not exist).

Does anyone know where I can find the maps online (and preferably combined in one map)?

Comment: This is available on Wikimedia Commons: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/0_Cassini_Carte_France_cadr%C3%A9e.jpg The rest of the category: [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Carte_de_Cassini).

Comment: @Semaphore: As you know, comments are ephemeral; you should write this up as an answer.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I was expecting you guys to VtC this for being a resource request.

Comment: @Semaphore: I will never close a *map* question - I'm a hobbit. I might abstain on the vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Semaphore pointed out that Cassini maps are available on Wikimedia Commons.
The combined map can be found here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/0_Cassini_Carte_France_cadr%C3%A9e.jpg

The rest of the category here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Carte_de_Cassini